# Train Gate POS tagger for another language

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger, gate

I want to re-train GATE pos-tagger for my mother tongue. Is train available in GATE? How should the training samples be formatted?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why you gave me a link for sentiment analysis. I already have samples to train a POS tagger but my problem is is it a must to get GATE tagger to work with rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default GATE POS tagger uses rules and lexicons, which means it has to be rewritten entirely for a new language.

It may be easier to try with the [Stanford POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) (compatible with GATE) which uses a statistical model. However you need significant training data which may not be available in your language. Check the link for details.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already trained a pos tagger for Stanford, my problem is my company needs one for GATE. i really have to do something and create the rules? is it a must?

Comment: You can check any of the available POS taggers in GATE, one of them is for sure the stanford pos tagger, so you can use it in GATE: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch23.html#sec:misc:creole:stanford . you can also train openNLP tagger and use it in GATE. Do you really need to use the default GATE ANNIE tagger?

Comment: This is the best solution, i can train openNLP tagger and use it in GATE. Ty Yasen.